# How can I redistribute a range of values without duplicates between 1 and 100?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of values between 1 and 100, essentially a sort of ranking that occassionally skips a few numbers (for example, the first ten values are `2, 6, 6, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13`). They're ordered ascendingly, so every number will be either higher than or equal to the number above it. Now, I wish to remove all the duplicates from this list while remaining between 1 and 100. So, for example, for the values above, something like `2, 6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16` would work or `2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14`. However, the formulas I've tried so far will either go over 100, go under 1, or create circular references. 
Given the nature of the list, there's very little chance of the amount of values exceeding 100, so if that possibility can be accounted for, it'd be a nice bonus, but it's not required.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a named range for all your numbers and name it `Source`. As an alternative, replace the named range `Source` in my formulas below with the sheet address of the range where you have your numbers.

[C2] `=INDEX(Source,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($C$1:$C1,Source),0))`

This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Observe that the COUNTIF range is defined one row **above** the row in which the formula resides. Its formulated with one absolute and one relative end. The end of the range will expand as you copy the formula down.

You can achieve a similar result using the LOOKUP() function. But since MATCH() finds the first instance, LOOKUP() returns the last. Therefore the formula below will return the same sequence in descending order. LOOKUP() is capable of looping on its own and the formula doesn't require array enabling. Just confirm it normally, with only <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[E2] `=LOOKUP(2,1/(COUNTIF($E$1:E1,Source)=0),Source)`

Observe that the result range is defined with an absolute and relative end, starting above the row of the formula as explained above.

Comment: Hm, that's not exactly what I was looking for. I might have used the wrong term when I said redistribute, sorry. English isn't my first language so I was struggling to find the correct term. What I wish to do is to keep the length of the list the same, but either add or subtract from the source list until there are only unique values between 1 and 100 remaining. For example, in the case of the 4 10's, the simplest way would be to use a countif formula to create 10, 11, 12, 13, but doing this would allow the list to exceed 100. Similarly, doing the reverse (7, 8, 9, 10) would go below 1.

Comment: For this we need to know how your list was created. If it's a ranking there might be two places of 99th which would result in there is no 100th in the list. If there could be two or more 100th the logic would look entirely different. Please advise. Your starting with 2 seems to indicate that there is no first. So, perhaps the ranking rule was that first and second were both ranked 2.

Comment: There could be two or more 100th. Without going into too much details, the list is essentially a "predicted placement" list based on past scores. The sorted scores are looked up in the list of the 100 biggest scores in the past and given a number from 1-100 based on where they would place on that list. This means that there could be multiple 1's and multiple 100's. Thank you very much for your patience and help, if there are any more unclear points feel free to ask.

Comment: A list of 100 different values where no number is <1 and no number >100 is a list of the numbers from 1 to 100. If your aim is to sort data you should be prepared to renumber your existing rows, meaning that the lowest number in your list must be given the rank of 1. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The issue was that the list could have any number of values up to 100, so the formula would have to work for various scenarios. Even in a list of 100 values, due to the lookup formula I used to get the original 100 values, the scores could still have duplicates. (aka two scores would be above the #100 threshold but below the #99 threshold, so they'd both get assigned #100). I'm terribly sorry for all the confusion, but thanks to this thread I have found a solution that seems to work rather well, which I will post soon. Thank you very much for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

In `B2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(A2="","",IF((COUNTIF(B$1:B1,A2)>0)+(A2=A1),B1+1,A2))
```

[image]

Edit #1

If data have repeated 100 as per OP's comment, then `B2` formula become :

```
=IF((COUNTIF(B$1:B1,100)>0)+(A2=""),"",IF((COUNTIF(B$1:B1,A2)>0)+(A2=A1),B1+1,A2))
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I first tried and it works for the numbers lower in the list, but when you get to the higher numbers (for example, `95,95,95,96,98,99,100,100,100`) it would go over 100 (`95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103`), which I don't want.

Comment: Pleas see my edited post addition formula for your new data

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for posting! Thanks to Bosco's original reply, I managed to fiddle around and find the answer myself. The biggest issue I was facing was getting a circular formula error, but by using Bosco's formula as a help column I was able to get it all worked out.
So, the solution holds 3 different columns: Original Data (column A), Help Column (column B) and Final Result (column C).
In the Help Column, I did as suggested, in cell B2 and copied down:
`=IF(A2="","",IF((COUNTIF(B$1:B1,A2)>0)+(A2=A1),B1+1,A2))`
This would occassionally create results over 100, so in the Final Column I placed the following array formula, which incidentally also accounts for lists longer than 100 entries, in C2 and copied down:
`=IF(B2="","",IF(ROW(C2)>101,ROW(C2),IF(AND(B2>=100,B3=""),100,IF($B2:$B$1000>=C3,C3-1,B2))))`
As an array formula, this needs to be entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter.
Thank you very much to everyone who posted replies, I'm sorry for my lack of clarity!